# view in a Laravel job

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel v8 job and I'm trying to create a view inside the job. Inside the view I'm loading an image using:

```
<img src="{{ this is where i pass the image location }}" alt="File not found" width="66%">
```

The thing is that the image is stored in the DB, before calling the view I pass a variable which contains the path to the image. I have tried the following but nothing worked so far:

```
<img src="{{URL::to($imagePath)}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">

<img src="{{public_path("images/") . basename($imagePath)}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">

<img src="{{asset("images/") . basename($imagePath)}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">
```

And other combinations but nothing worked. But when I do this:

```
@php
  $imagePath = 'xyz.png'
@endphp
<img src="{{URL::to($imagePath)}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">
```

It works perfectly. I'm sure that my variable contains the correct name as I have tried the following without the job and everything worked fine:

```
<img src="{{asset("images/") . basename($imagePath)}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">
```

Any ideas how to pass an image name in the view while being called in a job?

Edit: I'm calling the view from another view via

```
component('report/sales', ['imagePath' => $imagePath])
```

Please note I already dd($imagePath) in the view and it contains the path to the image

Comment: what should happen with the view in the job? Are you pre-rendering views?

Comment: Add the code on how you are queuing the job and how the job is calling the view. The data is not reaching the job/view since the @php worked for you.

Comment: Please check the edit I added to the post

Comment: Just some advice, img alt text is not supposed to be something like “File not found”. The purpose is to describe the image so that people with disabilities using screen readers can know what the image is (or people on a very slow internet connection, etc). Or even if the file truly is not found, it should describe what it originally was

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on how you saved your image in the database

- if in your BD you have saved "xx.png" and that in your server the image is in
  "public/images/xx.png" so to recover you will do `<img src="{{asset('images/'.$imagePath}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">`
- if in your comic you have rather recorded "images / xx.png" then to recover you will do `<img src="{{asset($imagePath}}" alt="File not found" width="50%">`

Comment: The path is stored as images/xyz.png when I stored the name of the image in a variable and called it as you mentioned it worked. But when I did basename($imagePath) and called it as you mentioned it didn't work.

Comment: do not put "basename" because "basename" removes the extension of the file

Comment: Not really. I already dd(basename($imagePath)) and got the full name.

Comment: ok I see it is necessary to check in this case the folder where the image is located

Comment: It actually works fine without the use of jobs but when I use jobs the image can't be uploaded.